# Find The Output Confusion

Tags: java, output

Unable to understand its output. how this operators works? Problem given below. Please help to figure it out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int p = 11;
    int q = 21;
    int r;
    int s;
    r = ++q;
    s = p++;
    r++;
    System.out.println("value of r : " + r);
    System.out.println("value of s : " + s);
}
```

Here the output is,
value of r : 23
value of s : 11. The r++ increased the value by 1 but when s=p++ its didn't increases its value? Unable to understand why? why here r value increased but not s value?

Comment: p++ increases the value after the assignment whereas ++q increases the value before assignment.

Comment: then why r++ increased by 1?

Comment: @IamSrkfan `r=++q;`

Comment: ++ will always increase by 1.

Comment: then why s value didnt increased by 1?

Comment: @elliott-frisch ??

Comment: `r = ++q;` This increases value of `q` first so it becomes `22` and then you do `r++` which increases value of `r` to `23`. When you do `s = p++` it assigns `s = 11` and then increases value of `p` to `12`. If you print `p` you'll see its value is `12` and the same for `q` its value would be `22` :) Hope that solves your doubts